# 75 Ohm trace with error markers in Altium

Tags: altium, error, drc

I am designing an RF PCB in Altium and I have set rules for 75 ohm as well as 50 ohm impedance traces. The picture attached shows a particular 75 ohm traces with error markers. The trace width is as specified by the rule and the DRC check does not show any errors. When I reset the error markers the markers do not go away. As you can see the traces are not the problem since the markers are also showing up on component pads.

I appreciate any comments.

[image]

Comment: Right click on the trace with errors. On the pop-up menu, scroll down to the "Violations..." item. Hover on that (or click it?) and see which rule is being violated. If it's still not obvious what the problem is, edit your question with the information about the rule being violated.

Comment: This is the issue, it shows no violations. Just markers. I am baffled.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's a violation marker? Those default to bright green. What you have could just be display override color for that net's connections.

Is the `*` column for the net checked in the PCB control pane, like this one?

[image]

Un-check your net and it should then only color ratsnest wires and not all objects tied to that net.

**Edit:** clicking around a bit more it looks like this feature is called "display override" in case you want to search for it on the Altium Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining a particular rule for these primitives that go against global rules (eg. track width), these errors will actually remain highlighted unless you uncheck the "Online DRC" option.